# Django related model field querying (mutual friends)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I have a friendship model:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friend1", null=True, blank=True)
    other_user = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friend2", null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = FriendshipManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "friendship"
        verbose_name_plural = "friendships"
        unique_together = ("user", "other_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} is friends with {self.other_user}.'
```

and this function to return all users who are mutual friends of two accounts

```
def mutual_friends(self, account1, account2):
        mutual_friends = Account.objects.filter(
            Q(friend2__user=account1) & Q(friend2__user=account2))
        return mutual_friends
```

Based on my (limited) understanding of how the query api works, I would think this should return all users who have a "friend2" relationship with the Friendship table where the "friend1" user is either account1 or account2. I'm still getting used to querying with django, so if someone can let me know what I'm doing wrong that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your model design doesn't seem right to me. As of now, you can put any `Account` instance as `user` or `other_user`, and as they both refer the same model (`Account`), while doing any retrieval from database, you need to account for both of the fields.

A better design IMO would be to use a `ManyToManyField` (many-to-many relationship) in the `Account` model to itself, as one account can have multiple other accounts as friends and vice-versa. So:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    ...
```

Now, you can add friends like e.g.:

```
account_foo.friends.add(account_bar, account_spam)
```

`account_*` are `Account` instances.

You can get all friends of `account_foo` like:

```
account_foo.friends.all()
```

Check out the [many-to-many doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for various examples of data integration and querying.

---

Now, to find the mutual friends of e.g. `account_foo` and `account_bar`, you can first get all the friends of `account_foo` and then see which of them are also friends with `account_bar`:

```
friends_with_foo = account_foo.friends.values_list('pk', flat=True)
mutual_friends_of_foo_bar = account_bar.friends.filter(pk__in=friends_with_foo)
```

Comment: its a bidirectional system, when a user adds a friend it creates two friendships, a is friends with b, and b is friends with a

Comment: @pererasys That's exactly what the above `ManyToManyField` does.

Comment: I also have more information about the friendship I want to store, with your suggestion I could use a through model, but what advantage does that have over my current implementation

Comment: @pererasys Like I said, when you add one account in the model, do you always add it as `user` or `other_user` or both? `ForeignKey` is many-to-one, I don't think you have considered that.

Comment: When a user A adds user B as a friend, two Friendships are created. 1st: user=A, other_user=B; 2nd: user=B, other_user=A, that's why I'm able to get away with querying just for Q(friend2__user=account) to get all friends account's